# Load Symfony subscriber from package

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony6

I am currently developing a library that will be used to intercept incoming exceptions, log them, and pass the to a separate micro-service for handling logs. So inside of the composer lib I am developing I need to have a event subscriber that will listen for exceptions and if the class that throws the exceptions extend our interface log it. Currently I have the interface

```
namespace LogLibrary;

interface ExceptionLoggerInterface
{
}
```

And the event subscriber

```
final class ExceptionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logger = new LoggerService();
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => ['logException', 0],
        ];
    }

    public function logException(ResponseEvent|ExceptionEvent $event): void
    { 
       dd($event);
       $exception = $event->getThrowable();

       if ($exception instanceof ExceptionLoggerInterface) {
          $this->logger->logError($exception);
       }
    }
}
```

And finally on any class from where I have to catch exception I have this

```
class UpdatePinCodeController implements ExceptionLoggerInterface
{...}
```

The problem is to actually make the subscriber work. I have the default doctribe setup, autowire is true, I followed the docs extensively. Any help on how to register the subscriber without actually writing anything in the services.yaml file?

Comment: This is in a package but not a bundle?  Bundles are how you integrate regular libraries into the Symfony framework.  Bundles are where you define your services and tag them with things like the kernel.event_subscriber tag.  The fairly new AbstractBundle class makes it fairly easy to do.  Just need the bundle class and probably a services file.  [Just follow the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html).

Comment: Off topic but having your own logger service seems quite iffy.  Are you sure Symfony itself can't do this?  The monolog bundle is highly customizable.  But maybe you have your reasons.

Comment: I have started rewriting everything as a bundle (Initialy it should have been only a PHP package and now the requirements have changed it to a Symfony pacakge). Thank you for you comment and yes I strongly dislike the idea for this library but as you know "Customer knows best"...